# hibernate (or SQL or HQL) finding objects who have a collection which is a subset of another collection

Tags: sql, hibernate, orm, hql, criteria

Story:

I have this User -> Role -> Privilege mechanism. Every user has some roles. Every role has some privileges.

```
CREATE TABLE user (id int);
INSERT INTO user VALUES (1);
INSERT INTO user VALUES (2);
INSERT INTO user VALUES (3);

CREATE TABLE role (id int);
INSERT INTO role VALUES (100);
INSERT INTO role VALUES (200);

CREATE TABLE user__role (user_id int, role_id int);
INSERT INTO user__role VALUES (1, 100);
INSERT INTO user__role VALUES (2, 200);

CREATE TABLE privilege (id int);
INSERT INTO privilege VALUES (1000);
INSERT INTO privilege VALUES (2000);
INSERT INTO privilege VALUES (3000);
INSERT INTO privilege VALUES (4000);

CREATE TABLE role__privilege (role_id int, privilege_id int);
INSERT INTO role__privilege VALUES (100, 1000);
INSERT INTO role__privilege VALUES (100, 3000);
INSERT INTO role__privilege VALUES (200, 2000);
```

(users, roles and privileges all have names and some other stuff. but i omitted them to keep the example simple)

then I have some Rooms. You need certain privileges to enter the room.

```
CREATE TABLE room (id int);
INSERT INTO room VALUES (11);
INSERT INTO room VALUES (22);
INSERT INTO room VALUES (33);
INSERT INTO room VALUES (44);
INSERT INTO room VALUES (55);

CREATE TABLE room__privilege (room_id int, privilege_id int);
INSERT INTO room__privilege VALUES (11, 1000);
INSERT INTO room__privilege VALUES (11, 3000);
INSERT INTO room__privilege VALUES (22, 2000);
INSERT INTO room__privilege VALUES (33, 3000);
INSERT INTO room__privilege VALUES (55, 1000);
INSERT INTO room__privilege VALUES (55, 2000);
INSERT INTO room__privilege VALUES (55, 3000);
```

Here is the deal: If a user have all the privileges required by a room, then the user can enter the room. If a room requires no privilege, then anyone can enter.

In terms of object, I have something like

```
class User {
  int id;
  Set<Role> roles;
}

class Role {
  int id;
  Set<Privilege> privileges;
}

class Room {
  int id;
  Set<Privilege> requirements;
}
```

now I have a User whose say id = 1. I want to know which rooms this user can enter. How do I achieve this with hibernate criteria or SQL?

I guess I can use some queries to find all the privileges that a user own (and store them in a set). And then I find the rooms whose requirements are a subset of this set. But I can't find the right criteria/restriction to this. Also, after reading some posts in stackoverflow I got the feeling that the whole thing can be done with a single SQL/HQL query.

Can anyone give me some help, please. Thanks in advance!

**UPDATE 1**

I have been working on this the whole night. I managed to get some results out

```
SELECT requirements.room_id
FROM (
    SELECT room.id AS room_id, room__privilege.privilege_id FROM room
    JOIN room__privilege ON room__privilege.room_id = room.id
    ) requirements
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT room__privilege.room_id, COUNT(*) as count FROM room__privilege
    GROUP BY room__privilege.room_id
    ) hits ON requirements.room_id = hits.room_id
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT user.id AS user_id, rp.privilege_id FROM user
    JOIN user__role ur ON user.id = ur.user_id
    JOIN role__privilege rp ON ur.role_id = rp.role_id
    ) up ON requirements.privilege_id = up.privilege_id
WHERE up.user_id = 1
GROUP BY requirements.room_id, up.user_id, hits.count HAVING COUNT(*) = hits.count
UNION 
SELECT room.id FROM room
WHERE room.id NOT IN (
    SELECT room_id FROM room__privilege
    );
```

which seems to give me what I want. I seems fairly complicated and I am not sure if I can wrap this into criteria or HQL.

I checked the answer from @Rajesh and @Erik Hart. Their queries seem to work with the example too. I am gonna do an analyse to see which one performs better.

Thank you so much for your help. I really appreciate it. If anyone know how this can be achieved by criteria or HQL, please don't hesitate to reply. Cheers!!!

Comment: in this example user id =1 can enter only room 11,44 right? if yes, will try the SQL

Comment: user 1 should be able to enter 11 (require 1000 and 3000), 33 (require 3000), 44 (require none)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL would be:

```
select id from room where id not in ( 
select room_id from room_privilege where privilege_id not in (
select id from privilege where id in ( -- can omit
select privilege_id from role_privilege where role_id in (
select id from rol where id in ( -- can omit
select role_id from user_role where user_id in ( -- if user table omitted: user_id=@userid
select id from usr where id=1  -- can omit
)))))) -- remove closing brackets when omitting subselects!
```

Checked this in SQL Server (user #1:11,33,44; #2: 22,44; #3: 44 only), table names slightly changed due to reserved keywords.

Line 2 selects room privileges the user has not, which would block him from entry. Then line 1 selects rooms without blocking room_privileges.

The selects on the main object tables can usually be omitted (except the first), but also be left for the safety of not having orphaned cross references (if not prevented by foreign keys, delete cascades).

This should return distinct room ids (without distinct/group by clause).

The IN subselects are usually translated into semi-joins by the database, NOT IN to semi-anti-join, meaning: no values from joined tables are assigned, and results will not be multiplied for multiple join matches.

Comment: I have a closer look at your query this morning. It tackles the problem from a completely different angle! good stuff! and it handles "If a room requires no privilege, then anyone can enter" out of the box. I love this! thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

First query is fetching all the rooms that user has access to
Second query fetches all rooms that doesn't require any priveleges.
UNION would give the desired result

```
select A.room_id
FROM( 
    SELECT room_id, 
           count(privilege_id) as count1
    FROM room__privilege 
    GROUP BY room_id) A
    INNER JOIN
    (
    SELECT room_id, 
           count(RP.privilege_id) as count2
    FROM room__privilege RP
    INNER join 
     (select RLP.privilege_id as privilege_id
      FROM role__privilege RLP
      inner join user__role UR
      on UR.role_id = RLP.role_id
      and UR.user_id = 1 ) T
    on T.privilege_id = RP.privilege_id
    group by room_id) B
    ON A.count1 = B.count2
    AND A.room_id = B.room_id
union
select R.id from Room R
where R.id not in ( select room_id from room__privilege )
```

Comment: union may not work as the columns are different for both the queries.. please correct it

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But it doesn't seem to generate the desired result. Testing it against the example in the post, it gives 11, 33 and 55. 55 should not be there because 55 requires 2000 which user 1 does not have. The correct result should be 11, 33, 44

Comment: it returns 11,33,55,44 (55 should not be there)

Comment: i updated a new version, tried it my self, this works.

Comment: Unfortunately, NHibernate criteria (which I prefer over SQL or HQL) don't have UNION. Don't know about QueryOver or LINQ.

Comment: Raj's query seems to generate the desire answer for the example. I will add more test cases to see if it handles edge cases. Thank you very much.